# How can I reverse the object entries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMSrd.png)

I want to start it from NV to 1952

Comment: You shouldn't care about the order of object entries. Perhaps you want to use a `Map` instead.

Comment: It's impossible. Numeric properties will always come before alphanumeric properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.keys and reverse method.

```js
Object.keys(object)
  .reverse()
  .forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item, ":", object[item]);
  });
```

Comment: You have not reversed the object properties, you've just printed the object properties in reverse order

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it doesn't make any sense to reverse objects as objects are not in order.

```js
    let dummyObj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
    let entries = Object.entries(dummyObj );
    let reversedEntries = entries.reverse();
    let reversedObj = Object.fromEntries(reversedEntries);
    console.log(reversedObj);
```

Comment: Object properties are ordered, and you can change the order. The code you wrote in your answer proves it. But, there is a rule that numeric property names must always come first and appear in numeric order, and you cannot change that